# How to delete the data for a student in the array and list box, and keep the array and listbox synchronized

Tags: c#

I have a 2 dimensional array, and a add button to add values from a text box into a list box and I have a delete button to delete a selected value from the list box and the array.

this line of code won't work because its a 2 dimensional array.

names[lstindex] = null;

```
    string[,] names = new string[10,3];

    const int STUDENT_NAME = 0;
    const int STUDENT_ID = 1;
    const int MAJOR = 2;
    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Close();
    }
    private void  AssignArray(int Row)
    {
        names[Row,STUDENT_NAME] = txtStudentName.Text;
        names[Row, STUDENT_ID] = txtStdBox.Text;
        names[Row, MAJOR] = txtMJbox.Text;
    }
    private string BuildStudent(int Row)
    {
        string answser = "";
        int UpperLimit = names.GetUpperBound(1);
        for (int column = 0; column <= UpperLimit; column++)
        {
            answser += names[Row, column] + "";
        }
        return answser;

    }

     private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //find location to use array
        int position = lstStudents.Items.Count;
        AssignArray(position);

        lstStudents.Items.Add(BuildStudent(position));
        names[position,MAJOR] = txtMJbox.Text;
        //find last valid subscript

            int maxIndex = names.GetUpperBound(0);
        //if using last valid  subscript disable add button
            if (position == maxIndex)
            {
                btnAdd.Enabled = false;
            }
    }

    private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = lstStudents.SelectedIndex;
        if (index != -1)
        {  
            //update array
            AssignArray(index);
            //names[index, STUDENT_NAME] = txtStudentName.Text;
            //remove old entry
            lstStudents.Items.RemoveAt(index);
            //put a new entry in that spot
                lstStudents.Items.Insert(index,names[index, STUDENT_NAME]);
            //highlight entry for user
            lstStudents.SelectedIndex = index;
        }
        else
        {
        MessageBox.Show("seleect student, then click update","error");
        }
    }
    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        int lstindex = lstStudents.SelectedIndex;
        //Delete the data for a student in the array
        //and listbox, and keep the array and listbox synchronized.
       names[lstindex] = null;

        lstStudents.Items.RemoveAt(lstindex);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To "delete" an item from an Array you'd have to shift all indices above that index down by one and then shrink the array so the last slot gets discarded.  *You could also use lazy deletion where you "mark" an index as deleted so you know it's safe to use (but that makes the code a little more complicated).

Are you **required** to use a multi-dimensional array?  Switching to a **Class** to represent each student would make life so much easier!...

Edit:

```
    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int lstindex = lstStudents.SelectedIndex;
        if (lstindex != -1)
        {
            //Delete the data for a student in the array
            //and listbox, and keep the array and listbox synchronized.
            //names[lstindex] = null;

            lstStudents.Items.RemoveAt(lstindex);

            // starting at the index to remove, copy the value from the next index up, then iterate
            // this will shift everything down to replace the item being deleted
            for (int i = lstindex; i < names.GetUpperBound(0) - 1; i++)
            {
                names[i, STUDENT_NAME] = names[i + 1, STUDENT_NAME];
                names[i, STUDENT_ID] = names[i + 1, STUDENT_ID];
                names[i, MAJOR] = names[i + 1, MAJOR];
            }
            //clear out the last entry:
            names[names.GetUpperBound(0), STUDENT_NAME] = "";
            names[names.GetUpperBound(0), STUDENT_ID] = "";
            names[names.GetUpperBound(0), MAJOR] = "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Then you could store instances of your Class in a List<Student>!

Comment: Yeah i'm required to use a multi dimensional array.

Comment: I'm just trying to be able to delete data from the array and the list box and the same time. But i can't find out how to do it.

Comment: Visual studios doesn't like this line of code. its saying "wrong number of indices inside [] 2 expected"                        names[lstindex] = null;

Comment: I also would recommend using a more OO approach. Storing stuff like this in an array doesnt very optimized to me. Dont forget to Keep It Simple, Stupid.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
names[lstindex] = new string[3];
```

Not sure if it works but I will delete my post if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your btnDelete_click should 'remove' an item from an array by creating a new array and [Array.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft.aspx) the items you need to keep. Like this snippet shows and can act as a drop in for your delete method.

```
// create a new array, one less than source
string[,] namesNew = new string[
    names.GetLength(0)-1,
    names.GetLength(1)];

int lstindex = lstStudents.SelectedIndex;
// calc offset because Array.Copy does not do 
// multi-dimensional arrays
int offset = names.GetUpperBound(1)+1;
// copy from source up to index 
Array.Copy(names, 
            0, 
            namesNew, 
            0, 
            lstindex * offset);
// copy remainder from source after index
int itemsLeft = names.GetLength(0)-lstindex-1;
Array.Copy(names,
            (lstindex+1) * offset,
            namesNew,
            lstindex * offset,
            itemsLeft * offset);
// dereferecne old array 
// and hold on to the new array
names = namesNew;

lstStudents.Items.RemoveAt(lstindex);
```